# 960px width responsive bootstrap container rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 to make a website, and I want the max width of the container to be 960px wide rather than 1200px. I know that on the [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) page unchecking the 1200px wide container option will not include that in the CSS, however my problem now is implementing that back into my rails app. I'm not sure where the bootstrap file is located or how I could replace it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you including bootstrap in your application? One way that makes it easier to override the bootstrap defaults is to use the 'bootstrap-sass' gem.

Comment: You need to replace those new generated `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` with the ones on your application. Either that, or you would need to add some media queries into your custom stylesheet to overwrite that functionality.

Comment: I can't seem to find bootstrap.css anywhere in my app

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap uses the class .container to style the width of the grid. So you'll want to override the bootstrap styles by adding this to a custom stylesheet (mystyles.css) that you include after you include the bootstrap styles:

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: That will remove the responsive feature he wants :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep the responsiveness use max-width instead of width. As Jarod Reyes indicates ... be sure to include these styles after you've loaded bootstrap.

```
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```